# Webserver isn't working after moving to new location

Tags: webserver

I had a webserver that was up and working. I recently moved to a new location and brought my server with me. It is now not working remotely but is locally. It's a Ubuntu system running apache2.

- I verified that it has the correct IP address given to it, and port 80 is forwarded to this IP on the router.
- On my LAN, I type in the local IP address of the webserver and I see the webpage.
- I did a `curl ifconfig.me` and put that address into Chrome and it does not show my webpage, just a 'website cant be reached'.

(for what its worth, my domain name A record was changed and properly points to the new public IP as well, but I am using the public IP for troubleshooting purposes)

To me, it seems like a forwarding issue, but the router settings have not changed since the move and everything look to be fine.  Other forwarding rules for other servers are unchanged and work fine.

Is there anything I am missing here?

Answer (score -1):

ISP was blocking, had to log into account and allow port 80.